# AES implementation for non-password multi-document decryption usecase

Tags: aes, pbkdf-2, salt

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt multiple user documents (consider text) in an application. Unlike the use case of passwords where decryption happens once during an API call, in this application during each API call the server has to decrypt multiple documents. Currently, I am using AES-256 with random salt and PBKDF2 (1000 iterations). As it turns out, this is quite slow because PBKDF2 is designed to be slow for the password use case where doing this operation once is fine from the performance standpoint. To put this in context, during decryption of a single document out of the total decryption time of 1.78ms for this single small text document, it takes 1.45ms to create the key using PBKDF2 with 1000 iterations.

I'm trying to improve the speed of this system. I'm looking at various ways of modifying the system. Which of the following would be the best choice for the given use case (where the server has to decrypt multiple documents in a single API call)?

1. AES-256 with a fixed (secret) key and random salt added to the content
2. AES-256 (with a fixed (secret) key + random salt to generate) PBKDF2 on very low iteration count (1 or 10)
3. AES-256 with a fixed (secret) key

Here's a code snippet to clarify the meaning of secret key + random salt:

```
func deriveKey(secretKey string, salt []byte) ([]byte, []byte) {
    if salt == nil {
        salt = make([]byte, saltLength)
        _, _ = rand.Read(salt)
    }
    return pbkdf2.Key([]byte(secretKey), salt, 1000, aes256KeyLength, sha256.New), salt
}
```

As per my understanding, both 1 & 2 are equally secure in this situation. Is this true?

Is there still any purpose of using PBKDF2 at such low iteration count (like maybe it randomizes key better)

Comment: Does each file is encrypted with a different key?

Comment: There's one single secret key for the application.